# Transform to a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let an expression $X^T AX+B^TX$, how can I transform it as $Y^T C Y$; where $Y=[X, 1]$,

and $C$ is expressed as (in terms of $A$ and $B$):

$$C=\begin{pmatrix} A & \frac12B\\ \frac12B^T & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

My question in case, the above expression is very complex in form (some other variables can be multiplied or added), in general what are the steps to find $C$?

Size of $X$ is $N\times 1$, $Y$ is $(N+1)\times 1$, $A$ is $N\times N$, $B$ is $N\times 1$, and $C$ is $(N+1)\times (N+1)$

[post on Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/201304/66369)

Comment: @user1551  edited

Comment: Right above the line where you say "I'm not sure what are the steps to obtain $C$" you're quoting an explicit recipe for how to create it. **What is your question, then?**

Comment: Yes, I was about to ask the same question. You only need to verify that $Y^TCY=X^TAX+B^TX$, don't you?

Comment: @user1551 I need to know how to find $C$, in general?

Comment: @HenningMakholm kindly see, if it is clear from the edits.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have already expressed $C$ *explicitly* in terms of $A$ and $B$. So, given $A$ and $B$, you know $C$. There is no case.

Comment: @user1551 suppose, I do not know what is the expression of $C$.

Comment: If you don't know the expression for $C$, then how on earth were you able to type it into your question? **It is right there!** All you need to do is plug in your $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I got to know form the link provided at below of the question, see the comments. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/201304/66369

Comment: Are you asking how to write the block matrix in Mathematica syntax? That is a question that should be asked on [Mathematica.SE].

Comment: **Do not deface your question** by removing the answer you already know!

Comment: I have already asked on Mathematica, not received the answer. So, I want to do the steps by hand not using Mathematica.

Comment: @user199: If you want help with writing something in Mathematica syntax, the people who know that are at [Mathematica.SE], and the question is off-topic here. If you want to do the transformation by hand, then **what is stopping you?** You have the recipe **RIGHT THERE IN YOUR OWN QUESTION**. Literally _everything you need to do_ is to insert the values from your particular $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I fail to express my doubts. Apologies for my ignorance. In the above post, I have expressed $C$. But, suppose, I do not know the expression of $C$, and I need to write it in terms of A and B. One possible way to start Y^t C Y = X^t A X + B^t X, then what is the next step?

Comment: But you **do** know the expression for $C$. It was explicitly given to you in the Mathematica comment thread you link to. Do you doubt that it does what you want it to do?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I do know the C from the link. But the thing that I do not know how he got C? What is the logic or step to find C?

Comment: @user199: Most likely he just wrote it down. It is not hard to come up with when you have a basic intuition for how matrix multiplication works. It is extremely unlikely that he followed any "series of steps".

Comment: The expression is not unique either. For example $ C=({}^A_0 \;{}^B_0)$ would work just as well. Probably the person who wrote your expression wanted to produce a _symmetric_ $C$ (which is convenient for some purposes) but he overlooked that you don't have a guarantee that your $A$ is symmetric in the first place, so his solution doesn't quite achieve that anyway.

Comment: Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$X^TAX+B^TX= \sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N A_{ij}X_iX_j + \sum_{j=1}^N B_jX_j$$

On the other hand, we have
\begin{align}
Y^TCY &= \sum_{i=1}^{N+1}\sum_{j=1}^{N+1} C_{ij}Y_iY_j\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N} C_{ij}X_iX_j + \sum_{j=1}^N C_{(N+1)j}X_j + \sum_{i=1}^N C_{i(N+1)}X_i+ C_{(N+1)(N+1)}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N} C_{ij}X_iX_j + \sum_{j=1}^N (C_{(N+1)j} + C_{j(N+1)})X_j+ C_{(N+1)(N+1)}
\end{align}

For these two expressions to be equal, we can set

- $C_{ij} = A_{ij}$ for $i,j \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$
- $C_{(N+1)j} = C_{j(N+1)} = \frac12B_j$ for $j \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$
- $C_{(N+1)(N+1)} = 0$

resulting in 
$$C=\begin{pmatrix} A & \frac12B\\ \frac12B^T & 0\end{pmatrix}$$